# How to find the "replace text as you type" in Word AutoCorrect option in Word with C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, office-interop, word-interop

I'm trying to check whether the word "CU" is exist in "word replace text list". I found out in interop.Excel and in VBA, we have AutoCorrect.ReplacementList. But in interop.Word is not.

So my question is how do i can check "CU" exist in Word replacement list by C#.
Thanks for your watching.
[image]

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)w;
_activeDoc = oWord.ActiveDocument;
oWord.Application.AutoCorrect.ReplaceText .......??????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of the AutoCorrect listing in Word use the `AutoCorrect.Entries` collection. The `Name` property returns the "shortcut", the `Value` property the text that replaces the "shortcut".

```
string acName = "";
string acValue = "";
bool foundit = false;
Word.AutoCorrectEntries ACs = wdApp.AutoCorrect.Entries;
foreach (Word.AutoCorrectEntry AC in ACs)
{
    acName = AC.Name;
    acValue = AC.Value;
    Debug.Print("Name: {0}, Value: {1}", acName, acValue);
    if (acName == "CU")
    {
        foundit = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (foundit)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found it: " + acValue);
}
else MessageBox.Show("Not present");
```